# Where does MySQL store "database-specific" privileges?

Tags: mysql

I'm assuming it's in the database folder. But where.. WHERE could it be?

---

The problem was solved by running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`. I copied over the `mysql` folder but did not restart the server.

Comment: Database folder? You mean database schema?

Comment: Is it in the information_schema folder?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have folders! It's a totally different way of thinking.

Comment: Well all my data is stored in folders. Each database has its own folder. Which folder is that information contained in because i need to COPY it over to another computer.

Comment: *"Each database has its own folder"*? On the physical drive?

Comment: yes. what i want to do is use scp to copy over all the privileges and users without retyping all the GRANT commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are normally stored to "mysql" database.

As http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//grant-table-structure.html shows, the table is called "db"

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> show tables;

+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
```

Granting access to a specific database, use:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: well i thought that's where it's normally stored but after copying it over, my user still had no "database specific" privileges.. not sure why

Comment: Also, always restart mysql after this kind of operations

Comment: i think my problem is `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` lol. thanks for reminding me

Comment: no need to dump, it works fine just doing `scp` even for databases 50GB in size. it all local

Comment: Ah, ok. I was just thinking "platform agnostic" :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `SHOW GRANTS` (or its more specific variants like `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host'` or `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER`) to get privilege information.

You can also get information from `mysql` database as shown in julumme's answer if you wish to get result as an SQL result set.